# Mongoose populate document

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I want to create a document, save it, and then return it with a field populated. Here is my code, but the populated field is undefined (instead of the user's name):

```
var doc = await new Documents({
  authors: [currentUserId, otherUserId]
});
doc.save();
return doc.populate("authors", "name");
```

(This function is async). I am sure that the user ids are correct because when I go to get this document later, everything works (the document's authors are correctly populated)

```
Documents.find(/* ... */).populate("authors", "name").exec(/* ... */);
```

How do I correctly populate in the first example?

Comment: doc.save().then(t => t.populate('my-path').execPopulate())

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know save has a then function. How would i return that though?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `execPopulate()` function to populate a **document**.

```
doc.populate("authors", "name").execPopulate();
```

---

> Documents.find(/* ... */).populate("authors", "name").exec(/* ... */);

In the this case you are calling the populate function on a **query** so `.populate()` works fine. But

> doc.populate("authors", "name");

Here you are calling the populate function in a **document**, so here you need to call `execPopulate()` to actually execute the `populate()` function.

You can read more about this [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_an_existing_mongoose_document)

---

Also, you are using `await` on the wrong place,

```
var doc = new Documents({
  authors: [currentUserId, otherUserId]
});
// await needs to be here
await doc.save();
return doc.populate("authors", "name");
```